# Possible to change AppDelegate at runtime

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiapplicationdelegate

Is it possible to change the UIApplication.delegate property at runtime to another class that implements the UIApplicationDelegate protocol so that from then on UIApplicationDelegate functions are called on the new class?

Comment: What is the advantage of this? Do you want to have a couple different implementations of each delegate method?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: The idea is to let the app load with a normal app delegate defined in the application, but then at some point (likely right away after launch) be able to switch to a new AppDelegate defined in dynamic library framework (using newly available support for that in xcode6/iOS8). I don't have access to the framework yet, so I haven't tried it, but will soon!

Comment: @stonedauwg Were you able to figure this out? I am trying something similar and switching appDelegate at runtime but it is crashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can very simply change it with `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate = instanceOfDifferentClass`.

Comment: have not tried this with a framework-based UIApplicationDelegate class like orig intended but the basics work like @AdamPro13 says